# Wondering if I need to implements serializable interface or not?

Tags: java, mybatis

I am new to MyBatis, I saw some code which define model as

```
public class model implement serializable {
    ****
}
```

but some codes simple define without serializable interface.

I am wondering which is better? Serializable is an empty interface actually.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. But nonetheless, you should look at what serialization is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the Serializable interface if you plan to serialize instances of your class. It's that simple.

Many do it out of routine, but the entire point of Serializable is that some classes can NOT be serialized correctly. By making you implement this interface, you make the conscious decision that your class, in fact, can be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

Mybatis don't require serialization. It dynamically calls constructor after executing query and create bean objects.

So answer is no you don't need to implement `Serializable` interface.

`Serializable` is a marker interface and has no method. It just tell jvm that you are intrested to serialize the type and rest will be done automatically.

Comment: How about hibernate?

Comment: For hibernate you need to implement `Serializable`.